# Java Debugger in Eclipse: Limitation on lines of code

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am working on a Java application and there are certain classes which are more than 60K lines of code. One challenge we always face is navigating thru debugger when lines cross 60K during debugging. When 60K is crossed, the debugger stops showing the code and values. One way we overcome this is to move the impacted function above 60K lines and then put the debugger again, but this process is inconvenient at times.

Question:

Where is the limitation, is it eclipse or java or something else which doesn't allow debugger to function properly beyond 60K ?

Comment: Maybe you should consider refactoring these large classes.

Comment: This sounds like a massive violation of the [single reponsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)  (and probably a few others as well).

Comment: I would love to refactor. Hands tied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation is given by the Java **bytecode** format:

[In the line number table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.12), the line number is stored as an **unsigned two bytes** quantity (`u2`), which results in a **maximum line number of 65 535**.

Apart from that, the effective limitation is given by the people who have to read the code. 60k LOC is far too much that it would be readable code.